# HandleBars HTML Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am just running my code locally. I am using handlebars and JS to accept a get request and display the data back to the page. The data is being received. I know because the data being input into the URL is viewable when I do a console.log on the the query.

But, the data should be displayed back on the html page after it is received, but it is not.

[My Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkUf8.png)

This is the code I am using for the JS

```
app.get('/junk',function(req,res){
  var qParams = [];
  for (var p in req.query){
    qParams.push({'name':p,'value':req.query[p]})
  }
  var context = {};
  context.dataList = qParams;
  res.render('junk', context);
  console.log('here');
});
```

This is handlebars, junk.handlebars:

```
<h1>You sent the following data in a GET request:</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each param}}
    <li>{{this.name}}: {{this.value}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you compile handlebars then passed context?

It should be something like
```
var template = handlebars.compile(templateFile);
var html = template(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a handlebars file like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each dataList}}
    <li>{{name}}: {{value}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The main problem seemed to be that you were referencing `param` but the array you were looping through in handlebars was actually called `dataList`.  The list tag also should be closed with a `</li>` and the `this` appeared to be unnecessary.